# Is FCM the Only option for Real time messaging for Android in Doze Mode. Can we use any other services

Tags: android

We are using Web Socket but are not able to maintain connection as Doze mode kills the Connection, We are not able to get messages or notification even when we have set Alarm Manager for 15 Mins. So need an expert advice of what exactly to do for Real time Notification? Save Batter.

```
  If there is any other solution need help very badly. Thank you. And if someone can assist of what Technologies WhatsApp Facebook and Insta Uses for their real time notifications.
```

Comment: No You can't integrate FCM in your api Service

Answer (score 0):

i know another Cloud Messaging like Firebase it called [Pushy](https://eladnava.com/pushy-a-new-alternative-to-google-cloud-messaging/) i use it , not bad but my suggestion is [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) it's too flexible and You could use easy in Your Application. you can find a lot of tutorial about Firebase Cloud Messaging.

hope it help.